# transform a path along an arc

Tags: objective-c, xcode, path, core-animation, transformation

Im trying to transform a path along an arc.

My project is running on osX 10.8.2 and the painting is done via CoreAnimation in CALayers.

There is a waveform in my project which will be painted by a path. There are about 200 sample points which are mirrored to the bottom side. These are painted 60 times per second and updated to a song postion.

Please ignore the white line, it is just a rotation indicator.

[image: situation]

What i am trying to achieve is drawing a waveform along an arc. "Up" should point to the middle. It does not need to go all the way around. The waveform should be painted along the green circle. Please take a look at the sketch provided below.

[image: what i want to achieve]

Im not sure how to achieve this in a performant manner. There are many points per second that need coordinate correction.

I tried coming up with some ideas of my own:

1) There is the possibility to add linear transformations to paths, which, i think, will not help me here. The only thing i can think of is adding a point, rotating the path with a transformation, adding another point, rotating and so on. But this would be very slow i think

2) Drawing the path into an image and bending it would surely lead to image-artifacts.

3) Maybe the best idea would be to precompute sample points on an arc, then save save a vector to the center. Taking the y-coordinates of the waveform, placing them on the sample points and moving them along the vector to the center.

But maybe i am just not seeing some kind of easy solution to this problem. Help is really appreciated and fresh ideas very welcome. Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you are taking your straight blue line, turning it into a circle, and drawing the waveform with respect to that?  (Imagine the blue line being between the green and gray circles).  Put another way, you're transforming the line relative to which the waveform is drawn?  Is there a maximum and minimum peak that can never be exceeded?

Comment: Right now im not doing it, but i want the waveform to stick to the green circle (which i just painted in photoshop). The result should be looking like the dark blue waveform i painted (also in photoshop). The waveform´s height is scalable, so i can edit its size. The Blue line is part of the waveform, but the y coord. is just 0. I hope i could clear things up.

Comment: I know it should stick to the green circle... I was just wondering if the blue line were turned into a circle, if it would cut through the middle of the circular waveforms.  Just trying to conceptualize the problem in terms of what you have.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, please bear with me. The blue line is actually part of the waveform. Its the path of the waveform. There no data in that section, which will lead to 0 in the y coordinate. So if you would turn the blue line into a circle there would not be any waveform left to see, just a blue circle. Im trying to get my head around your question :D

Comment: Ok, I understand.  Looking at it more carefully, I can see it's the "0 value" waveform.  I guess I was just trying to think if it would be feasible to map this "0 value" onto the points of the circle so every waveform point would be plotted with respect to that, but you'd also need control on the waveform direction...

Comment: Thats what i described in my third option above. I could precompute these positions once at startup and everytime the window is rescaled. Then map the points to their positions and move them in the direction to the center corresponding to their y value. It just sounds like the fastest solution to me.

Comment: Quick answer, only perform a simplistic sample calculation on the waveform, ie. do a low resolution sampling. To render in a circle, convert from cartesian to polar coords, and then render your set of points. Not posting this as an answer, but as advice for you to teach yourself.

Comment: In terms of sampling, simply get amplitude at a low resolution, for example, your radial sketch looks like it's about a 200px(radius) so the length of your render would be (at most ~1256px) preferably halve that and sample equidistant amplitude readings from your waveform. Render those as Y, on a path (step X by res, eg.`x+=2`.) you will probably now have top half of your waveform, copy, invert the y coords, render the other side, you have a reasonable approximation of the waveform. Do a polar transform, and you're done. See if you can reduce the res of your amplitude sampling.

Comment: `r = (x2 + y2)1/2` cartesian to polar.

Comment: Oh and by the way, this is assuming you already have the audio available at the start, don't attempt to do this live if you want your 60fps, for that you'd need to reduce your visible slot significantly.

Comment: Thanks slomojo, did the circle sampling just as i described above, but used absolute coordinates, so i wouldnt have to convert back to cartesian coords everytime i render - the path only takes cartesian coords. Performance is good - as i posted below.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, the most efficient way to go (in terms of CPU usage) would be to use some form of pre-computed approach that would take into account the resolution of the display.

**Cleverly precomputed values**

I would go for the mathematical transformation (from linear to polar) and combine two facts:

1. There is no need to perform expansive mathematical computation
2. There is no need to render two points that are too close from each other

I have no ready-made algorithm for you, but you could use a pre-computed sin or cos table, and match the data range to the display size in order to work with integers.

For instance imagine we have some data ranging from 0 to 1E6 and we need to display the sin value of each point in a 100 pix height rectangle. We can use a pre-computed sin table and work with integers. This way displaying the sin value of a point would be much quicker. This concept can be refined to get a nicer result.
Also, there are some ways to retain only significant points of a curve so that the displayed  curve actually looks like the original (see the **Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm** on wikipedia). But I found it to be inefficient for quickly displaying ever-changing data.

**Using multicore rendering**

1. You could compute different areas of the curve using multiple cores (can be tricky)
2. Or you could use pre-computing using several cores, and one core to do finish the job.

Comment: What i did is the following: Everytime the window is rescaled, i am sampling a circle (saving x and y positions) and saving a vector to the center. whenever i rerender the image, i am moving a point of a path along the vector to the center and repeating this for all samples. this is surprisingly robust. i can do 2000 points per frame with about 60 fps. Because all samples can be precomputed, there is no need for multicore rendering just for the display. Thanks for taking the time to explain it in such detail.

Comment: Are you using bezier paths (even to do angular, non curved, rendering) ?
I ask this question because if you are using bezier paths you can improve speed by cutting your path in several pieces (repeat the previous point in the next path to avoid having a visible cut in your path).
But you are probably already doing it – I just thought it was worth mentioning. Personally I found that 500 points paths were a good compromise for my purposes.

Comment: I am currently using CGPaths for rendering. I did not see any reason to use beziers because all lines are straight, going from one point directly to the next.